# Connect to server via Remote Desktop Connection. What kind of web hosting is that?

Tags: .net, iis, windows-server-2008, web-hosting

I am a .Net Junior developer with very basically hosting knowledge so I want to rent space on a server through I can connect remotely and install windows services, multiple databases and manage my websites on IIS. I know there are many websites who provide access on their server's space and using FTP connections or other tools, I can upload website files on the server's root but does not allow me to control to the OS, so can't install windows services for instance.

Working in my last company, now regret for not asking them, I used to connect remotely via Remote Desktop Connection to a server and get access to the Windows. They said the server is not owned but rented. Can anyone tell me more about this type of renting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use similar to "Dedicated server" plan, "Virtual Server" or "VPS". All of them are not free.
You can also use Azure by adding virtual servers

Comment: According to this link http://www.webhostingsecretrevealed.net/web-hosting-beginner-guide/ I think they are mainly the same just VPS is more restrictive, having not administrator rights I guess because of the other users on the server unlike Dedicated server where I am the only user. By the way, I can connect remotely, get installing privileges in both situations and run applications on the server. Is that so?

Comment: If you mean with 'VPS restricted' the hardware, you right, but VPS has all privileges inside the OS. You can do all in VPS and Dedicated server. But things like clustering.. must be discussed with hosting provider. If my answer OK for your question please do not forget to 'mark as answer'